# jQuery attribute selector match one or more

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have this selector that matches one or more attribute values:

```
var item = $(this).closest('.foo[data-category*="'+category+'"]')
```

This works well. (category is one or more comma separated words)

Now I am trying to use it like this:

```
if(item.attr('data-category*="'+category+'"')){ }
```

but its not working.

I though maybe try this:

```
if(item.attr('data-category').split(',').indexOf(category) > -1){ }
```

but this will throw an error if some of my items do not have data-category attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
$('[data-category*="'+category+'"]')
```

or

```
if ($(this).is('[data-category*="'+category+'"]')) { ... }
```

?

The first shoudl select all elements having an `data-category`-attribute that contains your `category` (which your question title implies is what you want to achieve), while the latter should do what your `if` examples in the question seam to be attempting.

Both can also be done in vanilla JS btw:

```
let elementsWithAttr = document.querySelectorAll('[data-category*="'+category+'"]')
```

and

```
if (this.matches('[data-category*="'+category+'"]')) { ... }
```

---

### Update:

After reading your comments, I want to add one more jQuery function that might help here: if you already have a list of jQuery items, and you simply want to get all of them that confirm to another selector, you can use

```
list.filter('[data-category*="'+category+'"]')
```

instead of walking over all of them and checking with `if`.

Comment: yeap nice solution as well, although running selector multiple times is a bit overkill, +1

Comment: I already have a jquery object (item in my example), and I need to test if object has category attr. That why I dont use this: $('[data-category*="'+category+'"]').

Comment: Well, `.is()` is likely doing what you need then. I just didn't quite know what exactly you were asking, since the title of your question contradicts the contents.

Comment: Isnt .is() more expensive than checking if data-category exist and then using split(',').indexOf(category) ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware `.is()` uses vanilla `.matches()` under the hood if it's available, which should nowadays be highly optimized and use the same internal representation also used to apply CSS rules in most browsers - so it's not any more expensive than applying CSS rules with attribute selectors in a CSS file.

Comment: There's also the alternative of using `.filter()` on your list of items and get rid of the `if` entriely

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I am checking item one by one, not as a group, so not sure if filter is useful here.

Comment: Yeah, I see that you are. The question is: why? But either way - it's .is or .filter, depending on your approach

Answer (score 0):

`jquery.attr` is **NOT a selector matcher**, but simply returns the item's attribute with that name. This is the problem. To check if an item's attribute matches one of a comma-separated list of values do sth like the following:

```
let itemCats = item.attr('data-category');
if ( itemCats/*attribute exists*/ && -1 !==(','+itemCats+',').indexOf(','+category+',')/*has category*/ ) {
     // matches
 }
```

you can even do a one-liner:

```
if ( -1 !==(','+(item.attr('data-category')||'')+',').indexOf(','+category+',') ) {
     // matches
 }
```

Comment: Why is this inside every brackets? ','

Comment: @Toniq It is a trick, the commas are used to help match category if it is at start or end of string.